# Can you say - I hope it wouldn't

Tags: phrase-requests

Is it a proper way to say:”I hope it wouldn't rain tomorrow?”, or should one say: “l’d hope it doesn’t rain tomorrow?”

Comment: Personally, I hope it won't rain tomorrow.

Comment: The second one is like you would hope not, but the first one makes it sound like 'it' has a choice to rain or not.

Comment: You can say, “I wish it wouldn’t rain tomorrow.” or “I hope it won’t rain tomorrow.”  But in context, “I hope it wouldn’t” isn’t acceptable.

Answer (score -1):

The first is appropriate when it actually will rain tomorrow (with emphasis on "wouldn't":

> "It will rain tomorrow."
>
> "I hope it *wouldn't* rain tomorrow."

The second is appropriate when it is really unlikely it will rain tomorrow (with emphasis on "hope"):

> "It's Christmas, so it will not rain tomorrow."
>
> "I'd *hope* it doesn't rain tomorrow."

In general, if you are hoping it doesn't rain tomorrow, you can just say "I hope it **doesn't** rain tomorrow."